# Cannot use new with expression typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface Window {
    AudioContext: AudioContext;
    webkitAudioContext: Function
}

let contextClass = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let context: AudioContext = new contextClass();
```

The last line is giving me this error,

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler treats the `contextClass` variable as an *instance* of `AudioContext` while in fact it's merely a constructor function for an `AudioContext`.

You can simply use `any` and the compiler will let you `new` it:

```
let contextClass : any = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let context: AudioContext = new contextClass();
```

Another option would be to introduce a `Constructable<T>` interface that will let you `new` up those types:

```
interface Constructable<T> {
    new(...args: any) : T;
}

interface Window
{
    AudioContext: Constructable<AudioContext>;
    webkitAudioContext: Constructable<AudioContext>
}

let contextClass = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let context: AudioContext = new contextClass();
```

Comment: Do we need the interface to be generic?

Comment: @Mark, No. Just thought it can be useful for other types as well. You can safely replace it with `interface Constructable { new() : AudioContext; }`. Or perhaps you'll want to rename it to `ConstructableAudioContext`, now that is no longer generic and specific to `AudioContext`.

Comment: My mistake was I was doing `import * as X from '@some/thing'`. What fixed it was `import X from '@some/thing'`. Where X exports a Class by default.

Answer (score 13):

You can't new up an instance. `new instanceofAudioContext()` isn't a valid thing to do.

Your interface doesn't match the API you're trying to use. In the browser, `window.AudioContext` isn't a instance of `AudioContext`. It's the class definition method, `typeof AudioContext`. You'll also have the same problem with the `Function`.

If you'd still like to keep your interface. Try this

```
interface Window {
    AudioContext: typeof AudioContext;
    webkitAudioContext: typeof AudioContext
}

declare var window: Window;

var AudioContextDecl = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
```

Or if you don't want the interface,

```
var AudioContextDecl = <typeof AudioContext>(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
```

Or even just use `any`. It all transpiles to the same thing.

Comment: Note that `typeof AudioContext` is `function`. It is better than using `any`, but far less specific than the `Constructable` approach in the other answer.